# Conditional Joint Distribution

Tags: statistics

Let the random variable X be be exponentially distributed for some $\lambda>0$ and let Y be a positive continuous rv such that it is independent of X. What is the conditional probability of X-Y given X>Y?

I don't really know where to start. Should I first find the joint distribution $f_{XY}(x,y)$ of X and Y? I know that X's marginal distribution is $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\lambda e^{-\lambda x}$ but what is Y's?

Then I assume I have to use the fact that $h(y|x)=\dfrac{f_{XY}(x,y)}{f_X(x)}$ but how do I account for X-Y?

Any direction would be very helpful.

Comment: Tip: *Independent* means what.

Comment: Cannot you compute $$P(X-Y>z\mid X>Y)$$ for every $z>0$? This is the ratio $$\frac{P(X>Y+z)}{P(X>Y)}$$ Which part is a problem?

Answer (score 1):

Well you know $f_X(x)=\lambda e^{-\lambda x}\,\mathbf 1_{x>0}$, however all you have been told about $Y$ is that it is *some* continuous random variable and is *independent* from $X$.

Then you immediately know that: $~f_{X,Y}(x,y)~{=f_X(x)\,f_Y(y) \\= \lambda\, e^{-\lambda x}\,f_Y(y)\,\mathbf 1_{x>0}}$

However, you actually want to find $~f_{X-Y\mid X>Y}(z)~$, which is a conditional probability *density* function.

So to get you started, by the definition of conditioning probabilities:

$$f_{X-Y\mid X>Y}(z) = \dfrac{f_{X-Y}(z)\,\mathbf 1_{z>0}}{\mathsf P(X>Y)}$$